# WebAPi is not returning correct status code for Value not found

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

When I do a HTTPGet[By ID], I want it to return an error code of Not Found if the ID is not found in the database however I am getting this code 200 and the response value of "{}".

What am I doing wrong?

```
 [HttpGet("{SessionID}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(CaseInformation), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<CaseInformation>>> GetCaseInformationByID(string SessionID)
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("SQlServer"));

        var caseInfo = await connection.QueryAsync<CaseInformation>("GetCaseInformationByIDSP", new { SessionID = SessionID }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        return caseInfo == null ? NotFound() : Ok(caseInfo);
       
    }
```

Comment: Why would `QueryAsync()` return null?

Comment: You probably meant to call QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync instead of QueryAsync.

Comment: What exactly does your stored procedure return - how many records if something does or doesn't match? Why does your c# method return a _list_ of entries? I'm also skeptical that this code compiles - QueryAsync should return an IEnumerable (or some other interface), not a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (caseInfo != null && caseInfo.Any())
        {
            return Ok(caseInfo);
        }
        else
            return NotFound();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking `caseInfo` is null or not. `caseInfo`is not null even when the ID is not found in the database. You need to check whether the `caseInfo` list is empty or not.

```
 if (caseInfo.Count == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(caseInfo);
```